# Common columns for all entity in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

let say there are different entity User, Role, Task

All these entities have `createdBy`, `updatedBy`, `createdOn`, `updatedOn` in common.

I want to know how can I create a base entity such that all entity extends base class in nest js using Typeform.

Answer (score 4):

This is the place where should you use inheritance.
Basically, the idea is to have a base class/entity that gathers common logic or structure where many other classes/entities share that common logic.

For example:
Cat, Dog, Elephant are all having similar characterizations, so we might want to gather all these similar characterizations at a single place in order to avoid duplication of logic and code.

So let's see the simplest example only for basic understanding.

```js
export class Animal {
    protected numberOfLegs: number;
    protected sound(): void;
}

export class Dog extends Animal {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.numberOfLegs = 4;
    }

    sound(): void {
        console.log('BARK');
    }
}
```

For your needs:

Export a base entity.

```js
import { Entity, Column } from 'typeorm';

export class BaseEntity {
    @Column()
    createdBy: string;

    @Column()
    updatedBy: string;

    @Column()
    createdOn: Date;

    @Column()
    updatedOn: Date;
}
```

And then inherit it from derived entities.

```js
import { Entity, Column } from 'typeorm';
import {BaseEntity} from './base-entity';

export class DerivedEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Column()
    id: string;

    ...
}
```

Please read about inheritance which is a basic and very important principle in programming and OOP.

Comment: I have a doubt this code will create a table Base Entity in my database, also each and every field will have this column right?

Comment: Dropping `@Entity` decoration from `BaseEntity` will avoid creating `BaseEntity` table. Edited the post

Comment: Yes that works but I am still stuck at one place `createdBy` and `updatedBy` are foreign key to user table, so will I have to maintain `ForeignKey` relation with `user`?